# Silverlight read file and copy stream without save file

Tags: c#, csv, silverlight, filestream

I would like to read and parse file csv without save the file. 
I try to copy an another stream but without success, i try to read and parse csv directly with "CsvHelper" without success .. 
Any ideas?

```
using (var sourceStream = openFileDialog1.File.Open( FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
{
   newStream = ((FileStream)sourceStream);  
}

using (var csv = new CsvReader(new StreamReader(newStream)))
{
   while (csv.Read())
   {
      try
      {

      }
      catch (Exception ex) { }
   }
}
```

Comment: have you checked https://github.com/kentcb/KBCsv or http://pastebin.com/f56674dfb

Answer (score 1):

You dispose the stream "sourceStream" is too early.

Try this:

```
using (var sourceStream = openFileDialog1.File.Open( FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
using (var csv = new CsvReader(new StreamReader(sourceStream)))
{
   while (csv.Read())
   {
      try
      {

      }
      catch (Exception ex) { }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thx for your response finally I find the good solution, I copy the data of the stream in MemoryStream.  System.IO.FileStream fileStream = openFileDialog1.File.OpenRead();
                byte[] textBytes = new byte[fileStream.Length];
                fileStream.Read(textBytes, 0, textBytes.Length);
                Stream stream = new MemoryStream(textBytes);

Comment: Why do you need another stream?

Comment: If the file is large, you will have an extra copy of the data in memory. What for?